# How do I get matching rows Left Outer Join

Tags: t-sql

This time I thought I had it figured out; but how can my addled brain explain this. No, for this I need the experts.

According to Jeff Atwood [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) Left outer join produces a complete set of records from Table A, with the matching records (where available) in Table B.

```
SELECT R.[Computer]
      ,L.[User]
      ,L.MaxDate
      ,R.[Notes]
      ,R.[ID]
From (
    SELECT [User], max([StartDate]) as MaxDate
    FROM <Table1> 
    Group by [User]
    ) As L
Left Outer Join <Table1> as R --Self join
on L.MaxDate = R.StartDate
```

MaxDate on the left always returns only one date for each User. This should be matched by exactly one matching row on the right. Or so I thought. I am getting multiple items for each date and user.

The purpose here is to return all the columns for each user using MaxDate to get the most recent date for each user. As the dates are unique, I should only get one row for each user, but instead I get several.

How do I limit the result set to the single matching row based on `on L.MaxDate = R.StartDate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get multiple matches from R if the same StartDate is found for multiple users. Add User to your join condition.